# Set a default request header using IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

Im developing a ASP.NET Core MVC App in which I want to set an authorization header for every request when the user reaches a certain page. Im trying to use the DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization from HttpClient Class.
However, it just doesnt set the header.
Here's my code:

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();
    //Some more code
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public MyController(System.Net.Http.IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
         _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public IActionResult MethodWhichIWantToSetTheToken()
    {
        var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "veryBigTokenHere");
         
       string abc = Request.Headers["Authorization"]; //Yeah, it's null!
       return View();
    }
```

Comment: `Request.Headers["Authorization"]` gets the header from request which arrived into your controller. `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` is settings the header in HttpClient, that means that all requests sent via that `HttpClient` will have the header set.

Comment: Are you saying that from if I write that line in another controller I'll get the value?

Comment: How are you using the `HttpClient`, are you sending some requests using the `HttpClient`?

Comment: Im not using HttpClient anywhere else

Comment: `HttpClient` has nothing in common with your controller. `HttpClient` can be used to **send** HTTP requests to some server. 

Your controller **receives** HTTP requests and **returns** HTTP responses.

If you want to receive an `Authorization` Header in your controller, you have to send it from your UI (or other client that is calling your endpoints). 

If you want to enable authentication (or authorization) in your app, I suggest visiting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and going through the official documentation.

Comment: I actually want to SEND that token to every other controller in every request. I just acquire it once from client-side.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "veryBigTokenHere");
```

use

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "veryBigTokenHere");
```

Comment: Yes, it will still show null.  As David Kaya wrote "HttpClient has nothing in common with your controller. HttpClient can be used to send HTTP requests to some server." But if you need to send httprequest  to get API data ( for example)  you have to use the syntax I wrote. If you want to keep a token between requests you can use cookies or hidden fields or bagview etsc....